# Object not assignable to { [key: string]: any }?

Tags: typescript

I have this chunk of Typescript code :

```
interface UnknownParams { [key: string]: any };

interface ComponentParams {
    foo: string;
    bar: string;
}

interface IComponent<ParamsType> {
    params: ParamsType;
}

type ComponentConstructor<T> = (new (params: T) => IComponent<T>) & {
    something: boolean;
    doAnything: (constructor: ComponentConstructor<UnknownParams>) => void;
};

const myComponentConstructor: ComponentConstructor<ComponentParams> = class {
    constructor(params: ComponentParams) {
        this.params = params;
    }
    params: ComponentParams;
    static something: boolean;
    static doAnything(constructor: ComponentConstructor<UnknownParams>) {
        constructor.something = true;
    }
}
```

myComponentConstructor.doAnything(myComponentConstructor);

On the last line I have this error :

```
const myComponentConstructor: ComponentConstructor<ComponentParams>

Argument of type 'ComponentConstructor<ComponentParams>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ComponentConstructor<UnknownParams>'.
  Type 'ComponentConstructor<ComponentParams>' is not assignable to type 'new (params: UnknownParams) => IComponent<UnknownParams>'.
    Types of parameters 'params' and 'params' are incompatible.
      Type 'UnknownParams' is missing the following properties from type 'ComponentParams': foo, bar — ts(2345)
```

I don't understand why my `ComponentConstructor<ComponentParams>` in not assignable to `ComponentConstructor<UnknownParams>`, cause any object could be assigned to `{ [key: string]: any }`, insn't it ?

EDIT :
After @DaGardner's answer, I found a solution that is to make `doAnything` a generic function with a type parameter instead of `UnknownParams`, but in my case, that function is part of a class as you can see in the code above.

Do I have to add the type parameter to the class like `ComponentConstructor<ComponentParams, DoAnythingTypeParameter>`, or is there another solution that could solve this problem ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The relation is the other way around. You can see it if you try to do something in `doAnything`:

```js
function doAnything(constructor: ComponentConstructor<UnknownParams>){

  return new constructor({ test: 3 });

};
```

this compiles just fine - as it should, since the constructor accepts, as you said, any object.

If we pass `myComponent` to `doAnything` `myComponent` cannot take `{ test: 3 }` and therefore cannot be passed to `doAnything`.

If this would be this way around:

```js
interface UnknownParams { [key: string]: any };

interface ComponentParams {
    foo: string;
    bar: string;
}

type ComponentConstructor<T> = new (params: T) => any;

function doAnything(constrcutor: ComponentConstructor<ComponentParams>){ /* */};

const myComponent: ComponentConstructor<UnknownParams> = class {
    constructor(params: UnknownParams) {/* ... */}
}

doAnything(myComponent);
```

It compiles, as the constructor of `myComponent` is less restrictive than the signature of `doAnything` requires.

#### Update after an substantial edit to the question:

I'm not entirely sure what you are trying to achieve but, you can fix the produced typescript errors pretty easily by reusing the generic type off `ComponentConstructor`

```js
type ComponentConstructor<T> = (new (params: T) => IComponent<T>) & {
    something: boolean;
    doAnything: (constructor: ComponentConstructor<T>) => void;
};

// and then adapting the implementation as well, note the replaced UnknownProps with the actual ComponentProps

const myComponentConstructor: ComponentConstructor<ComponentParams> = class {
    constructor(params: ComponentParams) {
        this.params = params;
    }
    params: ComponentParams;
    static something: boolean;
    static doAnything(constructor: ComponentConstructor<ComponentParams>) {
        constructor.something = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay I see — I have to made `doAnything` a generic function to amke this works : `function doAnything<T>(constructor: ComponentConstructor<T>) { /*...*/ }`.
But in real case, my doAnything is a member of a class, so I can't make it generic, or I have to add a type parameter to my class. Is it the only solution ? (I edited the question)